How replace some libaries migrating EsLint 9.0 to eslint.config.js?
I am migrating to new flat config of EsLint 9.0.
But in my old config , there are following plugins which do not support esLint 9.x
eslint-config-airbnb-typescript

eslint-config-standard

So I have to remove these 2.Is there some other plugin I can replace them easily ??
Thanks.
